# OpenShift Play Application Deployment

Tags: openshift, playframework-2.2

I just followed the steps as mentioned in the following Github repo to deploy a Play application to OpshShift:

https://github.com/opensas/play2-openshift-quickstart

When I tried uploading my sources to OpenShift, I get the following error:

```
remote: Stopping DIY cartridge
remote: Building git ref 'master', commit 54b44ff
remote: Preparing build for deployment
remote: Deployment id is 9379deb4
remote: Activating deployment
remote: Starting DIY cartridge
remote: chmod: cannot access `/var/lib/openshift/XXXXXXXXXX/app-root/runtime/repo/target/start': No such file or directory
remote: -------------------------
remote: Git Post-Receive Result: success
remote: Activation status: success
remote: Deployment completed with status: success
```

Why is there no target/start directory? Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stage task have been rewritten in Play 2.2:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.0/Migration22 (Preparing a distribution)

Instead of mentioned repo please use this one:

https://github.com/JamesSullivan/play2-openshift-quickstart

Answer (score 3):

If you're using play framework 2.2+, you'll have to change your openshift APP_COMMAND to start from target/universal/bin/{your-app-name} instead of target/start. 
You can modify this in the .openshift/action_hooks/start file.